# Qlik REST Connector - How to retrieve all paginated data by calling an API as to load the data to Qlik Sense server

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to load all paginated data from API (as shown below) to Qlik Sense server but it only gives first page data whereas my requirement is to load all the paginated data to the server.

I have to use `\XML/JSON script in the request body to achieve the goal.

However, tried with Offset pagination type but looks like Total records path is not specified by the API data provider.

[image: Load paginated data to Qlik Sense server]

Answer (score 0):

What about not relying on Qlik to perform the pagination?

Instead manually loop through all possible pages and when there is no data - break the loop. You will have define the total pages (set to some silly number)

**Pseudo code:**

```
// set the total possible pages
let customTotalPages = 100000;

// loop through each page
for a = 1 to $(customTotalPages)

// set the pagenumber in the body
// to be the current iteration number
let body = "<body>
<method>GET_N08_LIST</method>
<params>
    <fil></fil>
    <pagenumber>$(a)</pagenumber>
</params>
</body>
";

// load the data
TemTable:
Load * From ApiEndpoint WITH CONNECTION (
BODY "$(body)"
);

// check if the api response have any rows
let tempTableRows = NoOfRows('TempTable');

// break the loop if there are no more pages to process
if $(tempTableRows) = 0 then
  Exit
end if

// if the api response returned data
// then concatenate this data to main table (which is outside the loop somewhere)
Concatenate (MainTable) Load * Resident TempTable;

// drop the temp table in each iteration
Drop TempTable;

next
```

Comment: Should I execute this pseudo code in the request body? Can not understand the point that concatenating with main table. I am novice as long as `Qlik` concerns; so, please guide me how can I exactly achieve my goal using the code you provided here :)